# how to make my contact section responsive in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am stuck with a problem, I made a Contact Us page , it is properly working on desktop mode but when am trying to see in mobile view it is not responsive , can anyone help me to fix this error

This is the Contact Us page, I want its working on mobile view properly
[image]

> Contact.html

```
<section id="contact">
        <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="row text-white ">
                    <div class="col-6 ">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-3  icon-fot">
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9 text-form-footer">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Find Us</h3>
                                <p>Mreylebon Rd,Merylebon London,NW1SH,UK</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3 icon-fot">
                                <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9 text-form-footer">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Working Hour</h3>
                                <p style="display: inline;">Mon-Fri : 8AM-5PM</p>
                                <p>Sat-Sun : 8AM-2PM</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3 icon-fot">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9 text-form-footer">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Call Us</h3>
                                <p style="display: inline;">+123 456 7890</p>
                                <p>+123 456 7890</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3 icon-fot">
                                <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9 text-form-footer">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Write To Us</h3>
                                <p style="display: inline;">Office@noise.com</p>
                                <p>Press@noise.com</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100 p-2" placeholder="Your Name...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100 p-2" placeholder="Your Email...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <textarea class="w-100 p-2 mt-2" placeholder="Your Message..." rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br />
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block text-white font-weight-bold">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: bootstrap 4 have responsive classes by defining the tablet prefix.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

You need to use `col-md-6` class instead of `col-6` class in the parent column class like the below code.

```
<section id="contact">
        <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row text-white ">
                    <div class="col-6 ">
                        <div class="row ">
                            <div class="col-3  icon-fot">
                                <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9 text-form-footer">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Find Us</h3>
                                <p>Mreylebon Rd,Merylebon London,NW1SH,UK</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3 icon-fot">
                                <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9 text-form-footer">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Working Hour</h3>
                                <p style="display: inline;">Mon-Fri : 8AM-5PM</p>
                                <p>Sat-Sun : 8AM-2PM</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 ">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3 icon-fot">
                                <i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9 text-form-footer">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Call Us</h3>
                                <p style="display: inline;">+123 456 7890</p>
                                <p>+123 456 7890</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3 icon-fot">
                                <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-9 text-form-footer">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Write To Us</h3>
                                <p style="display: inline;">Office@noise.com</p>
                                <p>Press@noise.com</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100 p-2" placeholder="Your Name...">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" class="w-100 p-2" placeholder="Your Email...">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <textarea class="w-100 p-2 mt-2" placeholder="Your Message..." rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br />
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block text-white font-weight-bold">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```